# How to write a user defined function with a built in function as a parameter which have a parameter on which i want to run a loop?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to write a function that takes in data and model with a parameter range that I want to optimize and plots a line plot for the mean f1 scores and standard deviation of the f1 scores.

I tried using this but it is not working

```
def parameter_optimizer(x, y, par_range, model, cv=5):
    
    mean_f1 = []
    std_f1 = []
    
    for i in par_range:
        
        model = model 
        score = cross_val_score(estimator=model, X=x, y=y, cv=StratifiedKFold(n_splits=cv), n_jobs=-1, scoring='f1', verbose=2)
        mean_f1.append(score.mean())
        std_f1.append(score.std())
        
    # Ploting for mean f1_scores 
    plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10, 10)
    plt.subplot(2,1,1)
    plt.plot(par_range,mean_f1, label='Validation Score', color='green', marker='o')
    plt.xticks()
    plt.legend()
    
    #Ploting std for the cv scores
    plt.subplot(2,1,2)
    plt.plot(par_range, std_f1, label='Std of validation', color='red', marker='o')
    plt.xticks()  
    plt.legend()
    plt.tight_layout()


parameter_optimizor(x_train, y_train, range(1,11), GradientBoostingClassifier(max_depth=i))
```

When i am running this fucntion, I am getting the output as:
[image]

But my desired result is:
[image]

Note: I don't want it to just work for max_depth. I want a generalized method in which I can choose any algorithem with any single parameter to optimize.

Comment: Can you check and see if ```score = cross_val_score(estimator=model, X=x, y=y, cv=StratifiedKFold(n_splits=cv), n_jobs=-1, scoring='f1', verbose=2)``` is non empty?

Comment: why do you give `max_depth=i` in the function call? That makes no sense

Comment: @N.Kiefer I get it that's the wrong way. Can you please suggest an alternative way that could work?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, you can instance the model when you call the function, an then set the parameters in the loop. I hope I've helped.

```
def parameter_optimizer(x, y, par_range, model, cv=5):
    
    mean_f1 = []
    std_f1 = []
    
    for i in par_range:
        
        model = model 
        model.set_params({'max_depth':i})
        score = cross_val_score(estimator=model, X=x, y=y, cv=StratifiedKFold(n_splits=cv), n_jobs=-1, scoring='f1', verbose=2)
        mean_f1.append(score.mean())
        std_f1.append(score.std())
        
    # Ploting for mean f1_scores 
    plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10, 10)
    plt.subplot(2,1,1)
    plt.plot(par_range,mean_f1, label='Validation Score', color='green', marker='o')
    plt.xticks()
    plt.legend()
    
    #Ploting std for the cv scores
    plt.subplot(2,1,2)
    plt.plot(par_range, std_f1, label='Std of validation', color='red', marker='o')
    plt.xticks()  
    plt.legend()
    plt.tight_layout()


parameter_optimizor(x_train, y_train, range(1,11), GradientBoostingClassifier())
```